# Use html() method to display image?

Tags: jquery, html, image, default

I have an object include text and image. I want to display its image, but if this image is not avaiable, default image is displayed.

Syntax like that:

`$('#MyPlace').html(object.toRender());`

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please define exactly what you mean by "not available"?  How would one check the availability of the image?

Comment: I mean the image could not load, because it's not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$('#MyPlace img').error(function () {
  $(this).unbind("error").prop("src", 'default image path');
});
```

Comment: +1 this is a hidden features which not many people know. i would give  a jsFiddle sample as well ,if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's **.load** and **.error** events, see [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kfGUS/):

**Markup**

```
<img src="http://cdn.dreamincode.net/home/images/monthlygiveaway.gif"></img>

<span id="result"></span>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("img")
    .load(function() {
        $("#result").text("loaded");
    })
    .error(function() {
        $("#result").text("not loaded");
    });
​
```